# Since 03/12/1017 Not received notifications from azure notification hub

Tags: azure-notificationhub

On  sending test message (WNS) received back message:-

The Notification was received and dropped by the Push Notification Service as device in disconnected state

Everything has been fine for the last 2 years with no changes.

Comment: Even I started facing this kind of issues! WNS doesn't seem to be reliable, sadly there is no alternate for desktop apss

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of X-WNS-DEVICECONNECTIONSTATUS-disconnected error messages shown in the logs for your namespace. This happens when the device is offline and not connected to WNS. Can you check if that is the case with you.

Comment: I had a guess that was the case. My app runs in a worker role. How do I check the machine is connected to WNS? (Remote desktop currently disabled)